# Kullback–Leibler(KL) divergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Could Kullback–Leibler(KL) divergence be applied to measure the distance between two distributions of the same random variable conditioned on different things? I mean something like this $$D_{KL}( q(X|Y) || q^*(X|Z))$$
Is this well defined?

Comment: One natural way to define something like would be as $\sum_{y,z} p(y,z) D_{KL}(q(X|Y=y)\Vert q^\star(X\vert Z=z))$. However, it's not really a quantity I have seen in the literature.

Comment: I have a similar problem with KL conditioning on different variables! have you found anything about this?